# WarningMessage Property for APRegister not found

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

Why is the WarningMessage property for APRegister not found in APDocumentRelease

I'm working on APDocumentRelease on AppData.CodeRepository.PX.Objects.AP folder. On line 255, the code is giving error since WarningMessage property for doc is not found. I override the ReleaseDoc Method and tried to retain the code snippet but it gives an error if I included that line.

Comment: The method is not marked as virtual to be overridden in a Graph extension. What are you trying to accomplish with this customization?

Comment: can you provide us more relevant information, do you use Customization for this thing? or are you editing directly? screencap on what exactly the problem you are encountering